# Occasionaly web3 returns contract old state even though transaction is mined

Tags: web3js, parity

I have a method in my contract that is supposed to reset a list of items.

```
bytes32[10] public items; 

function reset() {
    items = [0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0];
}
```

In my app, I reset items before retrieving them using web3:

```
contract.methods.reset().send({from: my_wallet})
.on('confirmation', confirmation => {
    if (confirmation) return;
    for (var i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++i) {
        (function(i){
            contract.methods.items(i).call()
            .then( res => console.log(i + " " + res) );
        }(i));
    }
})
```

This usually works and I get resetted values. However, 10% of the time I get old values even though my reset transaction has been just confirmed! Furthermore if I check using Parity UI, the values are indeed resetted!

I'm using `web3 1.0.0-beta.18` on a private chain with a single node, so there's no propagation time either.

Answer (score 1):

Web3.js does nothing here than resting those requests to the node, the confirmation is fired if a receipt is available.
I would suggest upgrading to beta.21 and see if that fixes item, as we made a slight iteration, or waiting for confirmation #2

Comment: Thanks Fabian. I know from experience that confirmation is not fired at the same time as receipt. Also waiting for confirmation #2 means waiting 3 blocks on a single node, makes no sense tbh.

Comment: Somebody from the go team has to answer on that, if its the case its not good i agree.